# Multiple httpclient instances with same implementation in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I would like to call a third party API which provided us two different authorization token values. So we are getting two different sets of results back via invoking the same endpoint URL.

```
EndpointUrl: https://mail.yahoo.com/ 
Authorization: Token User123
//Do something with the response for User123
Authorization: Token User345
//Do something with the response for User345
```

In my client service, my wrapper function should invoke this API by calling it twice with different token values. Get the result and merge it.

Here is my service.

```
public class MailService : IMailService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    
    public MailService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<UserResponse> GetUserResponse()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_httpClient.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri + "/user-data/");
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I was using [Typed Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMailService,MailService>(client =>
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "User123");                
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mail.yahoo.com/");
})
```

**Problem Statement:**

What is the best way to retrieve the results? I am not sure if I should create two separate instances of `HttpClient`? I would like to avoid repetitive code if I go with two different classes containing their own `HttpClient`.

Maybe my solution lies somewhere in [Named Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#named-clients). I just don't know how to implement that gracefully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have posted a couple comments then delete, because this is a weird way to do `IHttpClientFactory` never seen it before. I just opened VS 2019 started a new .NETCore 3.1 WebAPI and i can't get it to run. The injection of `HttpClient` into the service is throwing a fit in my code. This runs just fine for you? You get an HttpClient in IMailService from the constructor?

Comment: @Andy It's completely valid, lookup "Typed HttpClient"

Comment: Weird. Can't get it to work how you have it. I will try in the morning when I'm not so tired.

Answer (score 2):

You can delegate adding the token header later for each message. Remove the auth header from Startup and add Http message handler (Create a new class "AuthHandler").

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthHandler>();

services.AddHttpClient<IMailService,MailService>(client => {                
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mail.yahoo.com/");
})
.AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthHandler>();
```

In the AuthHandler, you can add the logic to retrieve and set the auth header.
The override SendAsync method will be called every time a http call is made. Below is a sample code, you can modify as per your logic/requirements:

```
public class AuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private static string? _accessToken;

    public AuthHandler(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
    {
        _appSettings = options.Value;
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = GetToken();
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private string GetToken()
    {
        if (_accessToken != null)
        {                
            return _accessToken;                
        }
       
        _accessToken = "123";// Get your token            
         return _accessToken;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to retrieve the results?

Named clients are one solution, if you are certain you will always have two authentication headers. That seems very odd to me, though.

[`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync) is another solution. By calling `SendAsync` instead of `GetAsync`, you can provide an `HttpRequestMessage` that can have custom headers. `GetAsync` is essentially a wrapper around `SendAsync` for convenience, and you can use the lower-level `SendAsync` since you need more customization.

Comment: I don't have two authentication header, It's just there are two possible header values you add which will give different resultset. All other configurations for `httpclient` will remain the same.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. It's normal to have either 1 or N different tokens, but exactly 2 is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer, and this is more-or-less opinion based. I like my DI services to be decoupled from everything else in my project. Basically you are putting a configuration to another service in your `startup.cs`. I like to keep all that stuff in the service that consumes the `HttpClient`.

So when I inject the `IHttpClientFactory`, I do it by simply calling:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

And move on.

Now, in your `MailService`, you would inject it as so:

```
public class MailService : IMailService
{
    // or store this in your applications external configuration
    const Uri BaseUri = new Uri("https://mail.yahoo.com/");
    const string UserDataPath = "/user-data/";
    
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    
    public MailService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<UserResponse> GetUserResponse(string token)
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        
        var uri = new UriBuilder(BaseUri){ Path = UserDataPath }.Uri;
        
        using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
        {
            msg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", token); 
            using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you should use the `HttpRequestMessage` pattern and not modify any `Default...` properties of an `HttpClient`. It could be in use some where else in your application at that time.

Using `HttpRequestMessage` ensures you get a fresh set of headers that no one else can modify. To sum it up: `HttpClient.Headers` [are not thread-safe](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1085).

**ETA:**

Now that I think about it... that really is your question. You want to use two different headers using one `HttpClient`. It won't work in the scenario you presented. You would have to have two `HttpClient` with their own distinct headers.

So, if you don't want to do it the old-school way I presented, you should consider "Named" clients... each configuration has a different name.

Comment: So, As per your suggestion, I should be better at calling `_mailService.GetUserResponse()` two times for two `httpclient` instance. Is that right?

Comment: @Shaggy -- Yeah. Sorry for the overblown answer. It was late and I was over tired. The issue is if you create a single client for your controller, but want it to do different requests with their own headers, it won't work. you will get a race condition because each request will be competing for that specific header. You could even get a crash if you do two simultaneous requests and they both try to modify the header at the same time. So, you either need do do it with a "Named" client, or the way I am showing in my answer. A "Typed" client won't work here.

Comment: @Shaggy -- i updated my answer to change the signature on `GetUserResponse` to pass a token to it.